# jQuery ajax response own code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on an installation script for a PHP system. After the user has entered his/her database info, it's supposed to check if a connection can be made with it (using PDO).

I'm trying to accomplish this with jQuery (ajax) and ofcourse PHP in the background. Although I'm not entirely sure about my PHP code being correct, I do seem to have a problem with my jQuery. It returns the entire code of itself instead of the return string from PHP. I'm hoping any of you can see the problem. I suspect it has something to do with the `$form` variable. But I could be wrong.

This is the jQuery part:

```
$("#ins_form").on("submit",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var pass1 = $("#adm_pass1").val();
    var pass2 = $("#adm_pass2").val();

    if(pass1 != pass2){
        $("#background").css({"opacity" : "0.7"}).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#pass_error").html("<label class='red'>&raquo; The Admin account passwords don't match.</label>").center().fadeIn("slow");

        return false;
    } else {
        $("#background").css({"opacity" : "0.7"}).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#pass_error").html("<table><tbody><tr><td>" +
            "<img src='layout/images/loading.gif' id='loadgif' />" +
            "</td><td>" +
            "<label class='black'>Checking database settings</label>" +
            "</td></tr></table>").center().fadeIn("slow");

        setTimeout(function(){
            var $form = $(this);
            var $cacheData = $form.find("input");
            var serializedData = $form.serialize();

            $cacheData.prop("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr("action"),
                type: $form.attr("method"),
                data: serializedData,
                xhrFields: {
                    onprogress: function(e){
                        console.log(e.loaded / e.total*100 + "%");
                    }
                },
                success: function(text){
                    console.log(text);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('request failed');
                }
            });
        }, 2000);

        return false;
    }
});
```

This is the PHP response file:

```
<?php

require "classes/pdo.class.php";

// Define configuration
define("DB_HOST", $_POST['db_host']);
define("DB_USER", $_POST['db_name']);
define("DB_PASS", $_POST['db_user']);
define("DB_NAME", $_POST['db_pass']);

try {
    $db = new Database();
    return "Succes!";
} catch {
    return "Failed!";
}

?>
```

Comment: "It returns the entire code of itself instead of the return string from PHP." What does this mean?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I mean it's returning the entire html / jquery code. Like it's returning "view source" instead of the response.

Comment: PHP should not return value, but echo it

Comment: Have you tried inspecting your xhr requests? For example Chrome developer console lets you view your xhr request parameters and what the server responds with.

Comment: Your suspicion is, I think, well-founded. `$(this);` in your setTimeout method will refer to the function, not the form object that you're in. For fun, try replacing `var $form = $(this);` with `var $form = $("form#ins_form");`. What happens then?

Comment: Whenever I try to change `$(this)` it returns "request failed" as a result of a 500 error.

Comment: Can we see the form? And why are you using a `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've already found the problem. Thanks anyway. The timeout is just to simulate some progress instead of it working instantly. It was just something funny for me, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply forgot to set the catch correctly in PHP:

```
try {
    $db = new Database();
    echo "Succes!";
} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "Failed!";
}
```

So ye, I kinda failed. My bad! xD